# Getting TX is not defined when trying to send signed transaction

Tags: web3js, wallets, infura, sendrawtransaction

I am trying to learn how to send a signed transaction using web3 1.0 and Infura.io. I have node.js running locally for testing. I can successfully create an address and check balances but am getting TX not defined when I run the sendSignedTransaction.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/My API Key"));

// Get Contract ABI
var abi = JSON.parse('[{"MY ABI"}]')

// Define Variable for Contract ABI
var AK = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

// Buffer PK
var privateKey = new Buffer('Private Key')

// create transaction - to address, amount
var data = AK.methods.transfer("To Address", 10).encodeABI();

// object to hold the transaction data From Address
web3.eth.getTransactionCount('From Address').then(count => {

var txData = {

nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count),

gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(25000),

gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.gasPrice),

to: "To Address",

from: "From Address",

data: data

}

var transaction = new TX(txData);

transaction.sign(privateKey);

var serialisedTransaction = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serialisedTransaction);

});
```

I get the following error -

```
(node:16077) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: TX is not defined
at web3.eth.getTransactionCount.then.count 
(/Users/ryan/Documents/KapAction/public/send.js:39:19)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:16077) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async 
function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not 
handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16077) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections 
are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled 
will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am really new to this and am trying to learn but am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. You typed `TX` but never defined  anything called `TX`. This might be more on-topic on Stack Overflow. (Hint: `TX` was probably a typo for `Tx`, but you also may be missing a library.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most probably miss the [`ethereumjs-tx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-tx) node module. After you `npm install ethereumjs-tx --save` in your project, add this to the beginning of your script:

```
const TX = require("ethereumjs-tx");
```

Another, unrelated possible mistake is that `to: "To Address",` should be `to: "Contract's Address",`

Comment: Great thank you, this fixes my issue. I appreciate the help! I do get another issue though which is unrelated, it says my Private key length is invalid.. But I will look into what I am doing wrong there.. Cheers mate!